# First execution of workflow in the day always fails

Tags: workflow, development

I am experiencing a strange problem with a VS workflow deployed to the server.

The workflow that runs when an item is added triggers fine (`OnWorkflowActivated`). After this there is a condition where the values of one of the fields in that item is changed. In order to check if the item has changed I have written a condition `workflowProperties.Item.Update()` followed by `OnWorkflowItemChanged()`.

When the workflow is activated for the first time in a day it always fails. Any request after the first one goes through fine. Nothing gets logged in the Log folder either.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "After this there is a condition where the values of one of the fields in that item is changed. In order to check if the item has changed I have written a condition workflowProperties.Item.Update()"

Answer (score 1):

It may has to  do with the application start process, maybe you recycle the application every day  at night, and in the morning while the application starts again, triggers an exception on the application start event... you may have to add an application_error event listener on the global asax to check for any errors and log it to the event log.

hope it helps.